# Is there a way to require the Expiration date

Tags: expiration

I can't find a way for a section (a channel in this case) to require the use to enter an expiration date.

I know I could add a new field and require that field, but that would get rid of the default functionality of entry/expire date fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this with a little custom plugin. All you need to do is to listen to `onBeforeSaveEntry` events
and check if there's an `expiryDate` submitted.

```
craft()->on('entries.onBeforeSaveEntry', function(Event $event)
{
    $entry = $event->params['entry'];

    if($entry->section['handle'] == 'news' && $entry->type['handle'] == 'news')
    {
        if ($entry->expiryDate === null)
        {
            $event->params['entry']->addError('expiryDate', Craft::t('Expiration Date cannot be blank.'));
            $event->performAction = false;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Perfect example, that worked great. Naturally, I was hoping for something native, that wouldn't be dependent on anything coded into the template, but with settings or things. I'll work on it :)

Comment: Does anyone have a Craft 3 example of this? or a plugin?

Answer (score 1):

```
    Event::on(
        Elements::class,
        Elements::EVENT_BEFORE_SAVE_ELEMENT,
        function (ElementEvent $event) {
            $element = $event->element;
            //IF CAREERS SECTION
            if ($element->section->id == 6) {
                //IF FIELD IS EMPTY
                if (!$element->expiryDate) {

  $event->params['entry']->addError('expiryDate', Craft::t('Expiration Date cannot be blank.'));
  $event->performAction = false;

                }
            }
        }
    );
```

Just not sure on this bit:

$event->params['entry']->addError('expiryDate', Craft::t('Expiration Date cannot be blank.'));

$event->performAction = false;

Answer (score 1):

For Craft 3, I [created a module](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/extend/module-guide.html#preparation) and added this:

```
  \yii\base\Event::on(
        \craft\elements\Entry::class,
        \craft\base\Element::EVENT_BEFORE_SAVE,
        function (\craft\events\ModelEvent $e) {

            /* @var \craft\records\Entry $entry */
            $entry = $e->sender;

            //IF CAREERS ENTRY TYPE
            if ($entry->type == 'careers') {
                //IF "Expiry date" IS EMPTY
                if (!$entry->expiryDate) {

                    $entry->addError('expiryDate', 'Expiration date cannot be blank.');
                    $e->isValid = false;

                }
            }
        }
    );
```

Hope this helps!